# Does spark maximizeResourceAllocation override settings?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I was told that when `maximizeResourceAllocation=true`, it overrides `spark.executor.instances`, `spark.executor.cores`, `spark.executor.memory`, etc.

However, when I set the `maximizeResourceAllocation=true` with a node that has 48 vCPU, I explicitly assign `spark.executor.cores=32` , in Spark UI Environment tab, I see that `spark.executor.cores=32` AND `maximizeResourceAllocation=true`, does this mean that the actual `spark.executor.cores=32` or is it `spark.executor.cores=48`?

Comment: Yes it does. You can check the executor configs created in YARN Resource Manager UI.